# WIfi is not working on Atheros AR9285 on 9.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 9.04

Just now I have installed 9.04 in my Lenovo z570. I am new to Ubuntu. By searching on various community, I come to know that I need to install wifi drivers to make wifi run because the output of `lshw -c network` shows that wireless drivers are unclaimed and output of `iwconfig` shows `No wireless extensions`. My laptop specifications are as below.

- Wireless adapter : Atheros AR9285
- Linux kernel version of OS : Ubuntu 9.04

Please guide me from where to download this drivers and how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k#Get_the_latest_ath9k_driver
just follow the instructions and it should work by then. If not we will continue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.